# Google map, google-map api, same latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am developing a job portal and want to display job location on Google-map. So what I am doing is that I am storing latitude and longitude of the zip code in the database and I am able to display different location on map using javascript.

But the problem is that if the jobs are from same location means having same zip code then only one buble is visible on the map, but I want to display all the location on Google map so kindly suggest me the possible solution for this to display all the job location on Google map.

My code is:

```
var locations = [
    <?php
        for ($i = 1,$j = count($icon_pos); $i <= count($icon_pos); $i++,$j--) 
        {
    ?>
    ['<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><?php echo $icon_pos[$i-1]['title'] ?>,(<?php echo $icon_pos[$i-1]['location'] ?>)</a>',<?php echo $icon_pos[$i-1]['long'] ?>,<?php echo $j; ?>],

    <?php
        }
    ?>  
];
```

where `$icon_pos` is the array having details about the location.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: What research have you done?  What have you tried? [One option](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=overlapping+marker+spiderfier)